# $(this) value of form select with many forms with same field names

Tags: javascript, ajax, select, this

i have a lot of different forms with the same fields on my page
I like to retrieve the current value and print it to the page.
Now i get the value of first form but i like retrieve the current value from the form (the one i change)

```
<FORM method=post id=form name=form class=form>
<SELECT id=cal_starttime name=cal_starttime onchange=optellen()>
<OPTION>10:00</OPTION>
<OPTION>11:00</OPTION>
<input type=submit value=Save class=submit id=submit>
</FORM>

<script>
optellen = function() {
  var starttime = document.getElementById("cal_starttime").value;
  var endtime = document.getElementById("cal_endtime").value;
  document.getElementById("sumuur").innerHTML = (endtime-starttime);
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using `id=cal_starttime` in every form?

Comment: One more thing, your `<select>` lacks its closing tag

Comment: Yes in everyform the same values like cal_starttime  (maybe i can change that?)

Comment: And sorry <SELECT>  is closing  </SELECT>

Comment: Not sure yet if it is the cause of your problem, but the `id` attribute must always be unique, so try using `class` first

Comment: Is changed the SELECT 
.... $count++ .....
<SELECT id=cal_starttime_$count name=cal_starttime onchange=optellen()>\n";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by passing the event parameter in function.

```
<FORM method=post id=form name=form class=form>
    <SELECT id=cal_starttime name=cal_starttime onchange="optellen(event)">
        <OPTION>10:00</OPTION>
        <OPTION>11:00</OPTION>
        <input type=submit value=Save class=submit id=submit>
    </select>

    <SELECT id="cal_endtime" name="cal_endtime">
        <OPTION>10:00</OPTION>
        <OPTION>11:00</OPTION>
        <input type=submit value=Save class=submit id=submit>
    </select>
</FORM>

<script>
    optellen = function(event) {
        var stime = event.target.id;
      var starttime = document.getElementById(stime).value;
        console.log(starttime);
      var endtime = document.querySelector("#cal_endtime").value;
      console.log(endtime);

      //document.getElementById("sumuur").innerHTML = (endtime-starttime);
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it via all help in this form 
all id are unique now and workes form e.

```
$count++
<FORM method=post id=form name=form class=form>
    <SELECT id=cal_starttime_$count name=cal_starttime onchange="optellen($count)">
        <OPTION>10:00</OPTION>
        <OPTION>11:00</OPTION>
        <input type=submit value=Save class=submit id=submit>
    </select>

    <SELECT id="cal_endtime_$count" name="cal_endtime" onchange="optellen($count)>
        <OPTION>10:00</OPTION>
        <OPTION>11:00</OPTION>
        <input type=submit value=Save class=submit id=submit>
        </SELECT>
        <span id=sumuur_$count></span>
</FORM>




<script>
optellen = function(erbij) {
  var starttime = document.getElementById('cal_starttime_'+erbij+'').value;
  var endtime = document.getElementById('cal_endtime_'+erbij+'').value;

  document.getElementById('sumuur_'+erbij+'').innerHTML = starttime ;
// alert(starttime);
}
</script>
```